# Python 3 - Writing Dictionary Keys and Values to Excel Cells

Tags: python, excel, dictionary, for-loop, openpyxl

I am currently attempting to write a Python 3 script that reads and manipulates Excel files to tell me how often a purchase in a particular place was made. For that I am using the `openpyxl` module.

My script currently automatically creates a dictionary for me that consists of a unique key for every store and how often it was purchased from.
It looks like this: `{'Sains': 2, 'Sains Petrol': 1, 'McDonalds': 2, 'Council Tax': 1, 'Car Repair': 1, 'Steam Purchase': 1}`

The next thing I would like to do is to write the name of every shop and the value of how often it was purchased from in cells that are next to each other, like so:

> A3: Shop | number
>
> A4: Shop | number
>
> A5: Shop | number

Each shop and it's number is supposed to be in a new row.

The function to write to cell is `new_sheet['A3'] = 'Hello World'`. `new_sheet` is the name of the variable I assigned to the sheet.

I now want to write a piece of code that writes every shop and it's number to my new sheet.

I successfully managed to write a for-loop that lets me write a string to the cells on my sheet, but only as many times as there are entries in my dictionary.
The loop:

```
a = len(dict_shops_purchased_from)

for cell_number in range(2, a + 2):
    cell = 'A' + str(cell_number)
    for i in cell:
        new_sheet[cell] = 'Hello World'
```

So this is going to write 'Hello World' into cells A3 to A8.

I also managed to write a for-loop that let's me make the dictionary's key and value into variables:

```
for key, value in dict_shops_purchased_from.items():
     print(key, value)
```

My question is, how can I change the code so it will write the dictionary key in cell *Ax* and the value to cell *Bx*, because the problem is that

`new_sheet[cell]` comes from a for-loop and so do `key` and `value`

I tried the following:

```
for key, value in dict_shops_purchased_from.items():
    print(key, value)

for cell_number in range(2, a + 2):
    cell = 'A' + str(cell_number)
    for i in cell:
        new_sheet[cell] = key
```

But that only writes the last entry in the dictionary, which is 'Steam Purchase', six times

Any ideas how I could make this work?

I hope this makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cell_no = 2
for key, value in dict_shops_purchased_from.items():
    new_sheet['A' + str(cell_no)] = key
    new_sheet['B' + str(cell_no)] = value
    cell_no += 1
```

can you try above code, hope this helps